# Javascript: Change fields to read only

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a pdf file that changes the fields on the current and all pages before it to read only when the signature field on the page is signed.  All of the fields on the current page locks correctly.  However, there are some fields ("kvial" and "mvial") on the pages before the current page that remains active.  How do I adjust this code to make "kvial" and "mvial" on the previous pages read only when the signature field is signed.

```
// Get the current page from the event target
var currentPageNum = event.target.page;

// Loop through all fields on the page
   for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
var currentField = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

// Check if the field is on the current or previous pages. Make the field office read only on all pages
if (currentField.page == currentPageNum || currentField.page < currentPageNum) {
currentField.readonly = true;
//Make the field office is readonly on ALL pages
this.getField("office").readonly = true;
 }
}

for(var j=1; j<=15; j++){
this.getField(j+"kvial").readonly = true;
this.getField(j+"mvial").readonly = true;}
this.getField("block").display = display.visible;
```

I think I may have found another way to solve my problem, but I don't have it all the way figured out.  The "kvial" and "mvial" fields are radio buttons.  So, I used the code below.  The problem is the radio buttons are read only on ALL pages.  I only want the fields on the current page and the pages before it read only.

```
// Get the current page from the event target
var currentPageNum = event.target.page;

// Loop through all fields on the page
for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
  var currentField = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

  // Check if the field is on the current page or prior pages. Make the field office read only on all pages
  if (currentField.page <= currentPageNum ||  currentField.type == "radiobutton") {
    currentField.readonly = true;
    this.getField("office").readonly = true;
  }
}
this.getField("P5.C.block").display = display.visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want different logic inside your main loop:

```
if (currentField.page <= currentPageNum) {
    currentField.readonly = true;
    this.getField("office").readonly = true;

    if (currentField.page < currentPageNum) {
      var fieldName = currentField.name;
      if (fieldName.endsWith("kvial") || fieldName.endsWith("mvial")) {
        currentField.readonly = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Loop through all fields on the current page and previous pages (including the signature field) and set them to read-only. Then at the end:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
  this.getField(j + "kvial").readonly = true;
  this.getField(j + "mvial").readonly = true;
}

this.getField("block").display = display.visible;
```

Comment: I tried the code.  Now, the "kvial" and "mvial" fields on 1 of the prior pages is read only.  The current and other prior pages are still active.

Comment: Also, the signature fields converts to read only when 1 signature field is signed with the original code.  However, there's a lot of red sign here arrows without signatures that I am trying to hide (vs read only).